# How to allow user to change the version of the library which is used by a plugin in Gradle?

Tags: java, gradle, classpath, gradle-custom-plugin

In my [plugin](http://gradle-pitest-plugin.solidsoft.info/) I call static bootstrapping method `MutationCoverageReport.main(arg)` from a library which is a compile dependency of my plugin. I would like to allow a plugin user to change the version of the library which should be used (assuming the selected version has compatible API).

I could advice user to exclude a transitive dependency from my plugin and add a dependency to the library in the requested version manually to buildscript.dependencies.classpath in his build.gradle, but this is not very elegant:

```
buildscript {
    (...)
    dependencies {
        classpath('info.solidsoft.gradle.pitest:gradle-pitest-plugin:0.32.0') {
            exclude(group: 'org.pitest')
        }
        classpath 'org.pitest:pitest-command-line:0.33'
    }
}
```

I would like to be able to use libVersion parameter in my configuration closure, but I have some problems with two solutions I tried.

`1.` I could need to remove transitive dependencies from my plugin (an original library version and its dependencies) and add a library in requested version (from configuration closure) as a buildscript dependency.

In afterEvaluate it is to late (configurations are resolved) and I had problem to successfully hook with beforeEvaluate (is it triggered for single module project?).

`2.` I could change a classpath which is used to execute a static method from a library.

To do that I could create a custom class loader which would use my library classes (in requested version) before delegating to the parent class loader. I also would have to replace one liner with `MutationCoverageReport.main(arg)` with the reflection call using the new class loader.

Maybe there is a simpler way to modify a classpath by a plugin with which the mentioned method will be called?

**Main questions**. What would be the best way to allow plugin users to define the version of the library the plugin executes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22649935/313516) about executing Java class with a separate classpath Peter Niederwieser provided 3 approaches. In the end [modify my task](https://github.com/szpak/gradle-pitest-plugin/blob/master/src/main/groovy/info/solidsoft/gradle/pitest/PitestTask.groovy) to extend `JavaExec`. I set explicit set execution classpath which is separate from plugin execution classpath and can contain different library version.

The drawback is allows only to run main method, but it wasn't a problem in my case.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure this is what you're looking for, but here's how the Jacoco plugin allows the user to configure the library being used.

[JacocoPluginExtension](https://github.com/gradle/gradle/blob/master/subprojects/jacoco/src/main/groovy/org/gradle/testing/jacoco/plugins/JacocoPluginExtension.groovy#L38)

```
class JacocoPluginExtension {
    // ...
    String toolVersion = '0.32.0'
    // ...
}
```

[JacocoPlugin](https://github.com/gradle/gradle/blob/master/subprojects/jacoco/src/main/groovy/org/gradle/testing/jacoco/plugins/JacocoPlugin.groovy#L138)

```
class JacocoPlugin implements Plugin<Project> {
    // ...
    config.dependencies.add(this.project.dependencies.create("org.jacoco:org.jacoco.ant:${extension.toolVersion}"))
    // ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the idea. Unfortunately I already add a dependency to my custom config which classpath is later passed to the library as a parameter, but unlike your JacocoPlugin I [call](http://goo.gl/pqoIqw) `main()` from the library directly instead of using Ant (maybe I would help me). Because of that I would need to add a dependency to `buildscript.classpath` (to affect my call from a plugin). Unfortunately construction `project.buildscript.configurations.classpath.incoming.beforeResolve {}` as well as `project.beforeEvaluate {}` isn't triggered and later this configuration is already RESOLVED