# Execute Java class with separate classpath from Gradle plugin

Tags: java, gradle, gradle-custom-plugin

In my [plugin](http://gradle-pitest-plugin.solidsoft.info/) I need to execute static bootstrapping method from an external JAR to perform an analysis. Currently I call it directly from code with `MutationCoverageReport.main(arg)`, but this forces me to create a compile time dependency in my plugin which is [hard](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22584869/313516) to modify (choose a different JAR version) when executing the plugin.

I would like to call it using reflection and found some examples in Gradle code like `WorkerProcessBuilder` or `JavaExecHandleBuilder`. Nevertheless they are in `org.gradle.process.internal` package and I'm not sure if it is recommended to use it from the external plugin.

**Question**. What is the recommended way for Gradle plugin to run arbitrary Java method from external class with specified classpath?

Btw, I would prefer to not use an `Ant` task as it is a separate project and another layer of abstraction with its potential bugs and limitations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a couple of approaches that you could take to invoke a main method in an external Jar:

1. Use a `JavaExec` task, or a custom task that leverages the `project.javaexec` method.
2. Put the external Jar on the build script class path and invoke its main method directly or reflectively from a custom task. The external Jar could be a transitive dependency of the plugin Jar. Alternatively, it could be left to the user to put the external Jar on the build script class path (`buildscript { dependencies { classpath ... } }`).
3. Write a custom task that creates its own class loader, puts the external Jar on it, and calls its main method reflectively.

The first approach will run the code in a separate JVM, which is often desirable. The second and third approaches can also invoke methods other than main methods. In the first or third approach, the plugin could add a configuration which allows the user to supply the external Jar by declaring a dependency in the `dependencies` block. (The plugin could provide a default dependency.) This is what many built-in Gradle plugins do, for example the code quality plugins (`checkstyle` etc.). You may want to study their code to get some inspiration.

External plugins should only use classes from Gradle's public API, that is classes that are documented in the [Javadoc](http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/javadoc/) or [Groovydoc](http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/groovydoc/). (Not all internal classes have `internal` in the package name.)

Comment: Thanks Peter. Just for the reference. I went into `JavaExec` (point 1) as it was quite simple to implement and met my needs. Currently only a main method has to be called.